# Не понимаю как передать значение UITextView в письмо

Tags: ios, swift

Я только начал учить язык, так что, не ругайте сильно если я сильно ступил

```
@IBAction func PressButtonSupport(_ sender: Any) {
    let TextInTextView:String = TextSupport.text
    print(TextInTextView as Any)
    //TextSupport.text = ""
    ChekAlert(title: "...", message: "...")
    let mailComposeControllerView = ConfigMail()
    self.present(mailComposeControllerView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    TextSupport.text = ""
    
}

func ConfigMail() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let MailViewConroller = MFMailComposeViewController()
    MailViewConroller.mailComposeDelegate = self
    MailViewConroller.setBccRecipients(["***@icloud.com "])
    MailViewConroller.setSubject("FeedBack")
    let TextInTextView:String = TextSupport.text
    MailViewConroller.setMessageBody((TextInTextView), isHTML: true)
    return MailViewConroller
}
```

Я хочу взять значение из UITextView(TextSupport)и передать его с помощью MessageUI в теле письма определенному аккаунту.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось виной всему Алерт - он мешал открытию нового контроллера :)